# Change text size of <iframe> using inline css

Tags: html, css, iframe

I tried the below command but the iframe text size does not change, Is there any way i can do it?

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="**" height="230px" scrolling="no" style="font-size: 20px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: No, you can not do it this way. With `<iframe style="...">` you will always only be applying styling to the iframe _element_ itself, but not to any content inside of it. If the iframe content is from the same origin, then you could access it via JavaScript, or insert a stylesheet into it dynamically. If it isn't - then there is no way to do what you want. (Unless the provider of the iframe content was explicitly offering some method for that.)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the ***style*** of elements inside an `iframe` from the *parent document* is **restricted** if the iframe contains content from a different origin (cross-origin content). This restriction is known as the **[same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)**, and has been set due to security concerns.

However, if both the parent document and the content inside the iframe belong to the *same origin*, you can access and modify the elements inside the iframe using JavaScript. Here is an implementation:

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <iframe id="myiframe" src="iframe-content.html"></iframe>
  </div>

  <script>
    const iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe');

    iframe.onload = function() {
      const iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

      // Modify elements inside the iframe
      const iframeElement = iframeDocument.getElementById('elementInsideIframe');
      iframeElement.style.fontSize = '20px';
    };
  </script>
</body>
```